# how to get newWebView to zoom to fit screen for difference devices in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to get newWebView to zoom to fit screen for difference devices?

So I am create some simple HTML pages with a table, saving this to file (with the below meta tag) and then.  I've discovered the meta tag but even with the below, whilst it works well with iPhone 5, with iPad it only take up 1/2 the width of the screen?

```
 <head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
 </head>
```

Not sure if this is relevant however my config.lua has:

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
local width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.ceil( 480 / aspectRatio )
local height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 480 or math.ceil( 320 * aspectRatio )
application = {
    content = {
        width = width,
        height = height,
        scale = "letterBox",
        fps = 60,
        imageSuffix = {
             ["@2x"] = 1.5,
             ["@3x"] = 3.0,
        },
    },
}
```

EDIT: Setup code:

```
local displayW, displayH = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight
local webViewHeight = displayH - navBar.height

webView = native.newWebView( 
    displayW/2, navBar.height + webViewHeight/2, 
    displayW, webViewHeight 
)
scene.view:insert(webView)
```

Comment: Wait what part takes up half of the screen?  The webView object or the actual HTML page inside of the webView object?

Comment: the rendered html - I'll add some code to the post to show the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use the same code in your config.lua and to make it fit here is what I use for my webviews:

```
local _H  = display.contentHeight
local _W  = display.contentWidth
local SBH = display.topStatusBarContentHeight -- Status bar height
webView   = native.newWebView( 0, SBH, _W, _H-SBH )
webView.anchorX = 0
webView.anchorY = 0
webView:request( "file.html", system.DocumentDirectory ) -- make sure you choose the right location of your file
```

The API:

```
native.newWebView( centerX, centerY, width, height )
```

As you can see from my code, I have set the anchor point to TopLeft because it's easy to position it that way. Then, width takes the whole screen and the height is the contentHeight minus the status bar height.

This solution will work on all devices, iOS & Android.

Comment: I thought I had tried this first, and whilst it worked on the iphone when I went to the ipad it wasn't fitting the screen, perhaps due to config.lua settings....I'll try again shortly to double check...

Comment: Make sure to use the correct content height & width. Try my code and see if that changes with no changes to config.lua

Comment: thanks works - the mistake seemed to be using "<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">"